# Speed up video with FFmpeg with low I-frame distance

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I got a video with 60 fps and `h264` encoded (`.mp4`), audio layer is removed. Now I want to speed up the video 4x faster with `FFmpeg`, but I would like to have a very low I-frame distance to be able to perform very precise and fast seeking. I don't need a high compression. Does someone has an idea how I could achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [setpts video filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) to change speed and the `-g` option to set your group of picture size:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf setpts=PTS/4 -g 25 output.mp4
```

You did not specify your I-frame distance, so I used the arbitrary value of 25.

Comment: The I-frame distance should be as short as possible, in order to perform precise seeking. Is 25 enough, or should I go with a lower distance? As I said, I don't need to care about file size.

Comment: @kcpac Then you can set it to 1 – that should work.

Comment: @slhck Does it mean, that my video will consist only of I-frames?

Comment: @kcpac Exactly.